# How to emit event to direct parent in recursive Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a custom Vue component that is referencing itself recursively. On change of some input in the current component, I want to emit an event to it's direct parent component only, without emitting to all grandparent components.

What methods can I use to achieve this?

The code below is roughly what I have at the moment.

```
methods: {
    emitEvent: () => {
        this.$emit('someEvent');
    }
},
created() {
    this.$on('someEvent', () => { do something; });
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't emit to all grandparent components, unless you explicitly re-emit the event again, no?

Comment: You should call `$on` on the emitter, which is the child component, so assuming it is called `childComponent` you shoud write `this.childComponent.$on('someEvent', some function);`. You can also write `<child-component v-on:some-event="someFunction"/>` on the parent's template.